# Localhost not working on server 2012

Tags: wordpress, iis, server

I have my wordpress website and I'm using IIS. It's working outside and inside when you're browsing but when you type localhost in the server browser it doesn't work.
I've changed the host file in :\windows\system32\drives\etc\ and remove the comment from:

127.0.0.1       localhost

I've even typed https://localhost but it doesnt work. Can someone assist? It's also using an ssl certificate

Comment: Have you added https site binding in IIS?

Comment: yes I did. Like I said the website is working but localhost is not resolving when I type it in the server broswer.